# Ngrx effect parallel http call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an effect that should call two different APIs (API1 and API2).

Here's the effect

```
$LoadKpiMission = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(EKpiActions.GetMissionsByStation),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.apiCallsService.getKpi(action.payload, '2016-04-18').pipe(
        map(trips => ({ type: EKpiActions.GetMissionsSuccess, payload: trips })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Here's the structure of the service

```
getKpi(station: number, date: string) {
  let Kpi = `http://192.168.208.25:8998/api/scheduling/circulation_by_date_and_station?orig=${station}&date=${date}`;
  return this.http.get<ISchedules>(API1).pipe(
    map(data => {
      return this.formatDataToKpi1(data);
    })
  );
}
```

However, I have to retrieve additional data from `API2` and merge it with the data returned from `API1`.

I should do that inside the `formatDataToKpi1` function.

I would like to know how to run requests in parallel and pass the returned responses to `formatDataToKpi1` and do treatment then return to the effect ?

Comment: Have a look at `forkJoin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `forkJoin` RxJS operator.

As stated on the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html),

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

This way, when the observables from both requests have been completed, it will be returned, and you can carry out the subsequent operations.

```
$LoadKpiMission = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<any>(EKpiActions.GetMissionsByStation),
    mergeMap(action =>
      const getKpi = this.apiCallsService.getKpi(action.payload, '2016-04-18');
      const getKpi2 = this.apiCallsService.getKpi2();

      forkJoin(getKpi, getKpi2).subscribe(([res1, res2] => {
        // do the rest here
      });

    )
  )
);
```

---

EDIT: Looks like I have initially misunderstood your question - Was a bit confused by the variable names

```
getKpi(station: number, date: string) {
  let Kpi = `http://192.168.208.25:8998/api/scheduling/circulation_by_date_and_station?orig=${station}&date=${date}`;

  const api1 = this.http.get<ISchedules>(API1);
  const api2 = this.http.get<ISchedules>(API2);

  return forkJoin(api1, api2).pipe(
    map(data => {
      return this.formatDataToKpi1(data);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I should make all calls inside ’getKpi‘ function and send API calls response data to formatdatatokpi1.. and not use distinct functions.. formatkpidata will transform the result of two http calls

Comment: @infodev ahh I understand now. I have edited my code