# combine results of two http.get calls using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I do a call to two different api's (two different online stores), each returns similar data. Both have some pagination information as well as a nested array of items (list of orders) in them. I need to combine these objects to display the completed list of items in order of date purchased. I also need to figure out how to maintain pagination data because the lists are too large to pull in completely so I will have to get further data from both calls to fill subsequent pages.

I am using angular with rxjs. Objects look like this:

Response One:

````
```{
"startIx": 0,
"page": 1,
"orders":[
    {"orderNumber":"756984",
    "date":"2020-04-02",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":7.84,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]},
    {"orderNumber":"756985",
    "date":"2020-04-03",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":8.54,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
        }]}],
"totalOrders":2
}```
````

Response Two:

````
```{
"startIx": 0,
"page": 1,
"orders":[
    {"orderNumber":"756984",
    "date":"2020-04-02",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":7.84,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]},
    {"orderNumber":"756985",
    "date":"2020-04-03",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":8.54,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
        }]}],
"totalOrders":2
}```
````

Desired outcome is something like this, with all the Orders from Response two added into it and the total updated..

````
```{
"startIx": 0,
"page": 1,
"orders":[
    {"orderNumber":"756984",
    "date":"2020-04-02",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":7.84,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]},
    {"orderNumber":"756985",
    "date":"2020-04-03",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":8.54,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]},
    {"orderNumber":"756984",
    "date":"2020-04-02",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":7.84,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]},
    {"orderNumber":"756985",
    "date":"2020-04-03",
    "status":"ORDER_PARTIALLY_PROCESSED",
    "price":8.54,
    "links":[
        {"rel":"store.order",
        "href":"history.jsf"
    }]}],
"totalOrders":4
}```
````

I'm very new to angular and especially rxjs and ngrx so I am looking for some advice on what the best method would be to combine the lists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not particularly clear what you mean by "combine the lists". Could you please provide an example of the 2 lists and the expected output. It's also not clear why you mention ngrx - that doesn't seem relevant here?

Comment: Welcome @jenny, It's not clearly understandable from your question. But some how i have given an answer it may help you.

Comment: Have a look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668717/10959940)! It has an example which achieves what you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my question. @KurtHamilton, I have updated my question to be a bit more clear about the outcome I'm looking for and you are probably correct and the ngrx is not important in this case.

Comment: @user2089677 Thank you so much for taking the time to post an answer to my question. I am giving it a try now and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @jenny i have updated my answer. check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-examples

Comment: @user2089677 Thank you very much for your updated response. It worked beautifully for me! I have marked it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. different api's (two different online stores) use "forkjoin"
2. combine these objects to display

   ```
   1. forkJoin([api1, api2]).subscribe(response => {
   // response[0] is api1(response)
   // response[1] is api2(response)
   // 2. combine both response data to display
   });
   ```

[sample-forkjoin](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-examples)