# Is there a way to make a method return contorl only after all the callbacks used inside it are invoked?

Tags: angular, typescript

My angular code

```
ngOnInit(){
        console.log("invoking method");
        this.getStatus(this.transferDTO);
        console.log("method invoke control returned control returned");
}

        getStatus(transferDTO){
          this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe();
        this.queryResourceService.getStockStocksIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe();
    }
```

Here the `getStatus` method is returning control before the call back functions are invoked.

Here ofcourse I can refactor the code like following

```
ngOnInit(){

        console.log("invoking method");
        this.getStatus(this.transferDTO);
}
       getStatus(transferDTO){
          this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe((data)=>{this.getStatus2(data)});
    }
    getStatus2(data){
    this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO).subscribe(controlReturned());
    }
    controlReturned(){
        console.log("method invoke control returned control returned");
    }
```

but I don't want getStatus1 to be invoked only after the callback inside the getStatus is invoked. I need both of the methods to be invoked independently, but function controlReturned() should be invoked only when both the callbacks are executed. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use forkjoin, I have an example here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668717/10959940)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best use case which [rxjs forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) solves:

Query two or more Observables parallelly but only return once all of them have resolved.

```
getStatus(transferDTO){
        forkJoin(
            this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO),
            this.queryResourceService.getStockStocksIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO)
        ).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
            // call your control here
        });
}
```

P.S. You have interestingly long function names.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pipe and mergeMap to chain Observables

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("invoking method");
    this.getStatus(this.transferDTO);
  }

  getStatus(transferDTO) {
     getStatusObservable(transferDTO)
      .subscribe(() => {});
  }
  getStatusObservable(transferDTO) {
    return this.queryResourceService
      .getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(transferDTO)
      .pipe(
         mergeMap(() => getStatus2Observable(transferDTO))
         tap(controlReturned)
       );
  }

  getStatus2Observable(data) {
    return this.queryResourceService.getInventoryStatusIdByStatusNameAndStatusTypeUsingGET(data);
  }
  controlReturned(){
    console.log("method invoke control returned control returned");
  }
```